# How to get input in collections using for loop?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to get input in collections using for loop but somehow output displays 0th position empty

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();

String abc;
for (int i = a; i > 0; i--) {
  abc = sc.nextLine();
  b.add(abc);
}
```

I expect output to be:

```
[a, d, b, c, e]
```

but actual output is:

```
[, a, d, b, c]
```

Comment: As explained in the linked duplicate, you want `int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());` instead of using `nextInt`.

Comment: Note that your `for` loop is kind of unusual. Idiomatic is to create an increasing index, so `for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sc.nextLine()` to skip the enter key:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a;
String abc;
a = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = a; i > 0; i--) {
   abc = sc.nextLine();
   b.add(abc);
}
```

Comment: @GBlodgett my bad. I edited the post.